# How to form a plane surfaces using 8 points?

Tags: python, arrays, 3d, surface, plane

I have plotted my 8 corner points with center of a cuboid as in figure [image: 8_corner_points_with center].

I have tried with the scatter but now i want the surface plot connecting these 8 points.

when i have tried with the surface plot i am unable to attend to that. Can you please suggest any solution for that

```
l = 0.3 
w = 0.4
h = 0.1
center = 
 [2.10737, -0.100085, 0.716869]
F= 
   [[array([[1.]]) array([[-0.001]]) array([[-0.017]])]
 [array([[0.]]) array([[-0.999]]) array([[0.037]])]
 [array([[0.017]]) array([[0.037]]) array([[0.999]])]]


def cuboid(center, size):
    ox, oy, oz = center
    l, w, h = size

    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d') ##plot the project cuboid

    X=[ox-l/2,ox-l/2,ox-l/2,ox-l/2,ox+l/2,ox+l/2,ox+l/2,ox+l/2]
    Y=[oy+w/2,oy-w/2,oy-w/2,oy+w/2,oy+w/2,oy-w/2,oy-w/2,oy+w/2]
    Z=[oz-h/2,oz-h/2,oz+h/2,oz+h/2,oz+h/2,oz+h/2,oz-h/2,oz-h/2]

    X_new = ([])
    Y_new = ([])
    Z_new = ([])

    for i in range(0,8):

        c=np.matrix([[X[i]],
                    [Y[i]],
                    [Z[i]]])
        u=F*c

        X_new = np.append(X_new, u.item(0))
        Y_new = np.append(Y_new, u.item(1))
        Z_new = np.append(Z_new, u.item(2))

    ax.scatter(X_new,Y_new,Z_new,c='darkred',marker='o')  #the  plot of points after rotated
    ax.scatter(ox,oy,oz,c='crimson',marker='o')  #the previous plot of points before rotated



    ## Add title 
    plt.title('Plot_for_PSM', fontsize=20)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

    ##labelling the axes
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')
```

Comment: You can use plot3D to connect points

Comment: proposed an exemple of plot3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here a solution.

```
###Added import
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection

###Addded size and center in this format in order to manipulate them easily
size = [0.3, 0.4, 0.1]
center = [2.10737, -0.100085, 0.716869]

###This numpy vector will be used to store the position of the sides
side = np.zeros((8,3))

###Just re-ordered your matrix in some np.arrays
F = [[np.array([1., -0.001, -0.017])],
    [np.array([0., -0.999, 0.037])],
    [np.array([0.017, 0.037, 0.999])]]

def cuboid(center, size):
    ox, oy, oz = center
    l, w, h = size

    ###Added the fig in order to be able to plot it later
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d') ##plot the project cuboid

    X=[ox-l/2,ox-l/2,ox-l/2,ox-l/2,ox+l/2,ox+l/2,ox+l/2,ox+l/2]
    Y=[oy+w/2,oy-w/2,oy-w/2,oy+w/2,oy+w/2,oy-w/2,oy-w/2,oy+w/2]
    Z=[oz-h/2,oz-h/2,oz+h/2,oz+h/2,oz+h/2,oz+h/2,oz-h/2,oz-h/2]

    X_new = ([])
    Y_new = ([])
    Z_new = ([])

    for i in range(0,8):

        c=np.matrix([[X[i]],
                    [Y[i]],
                    [Z[i]]])
        u=F*c

        X_new = np.append(X_new, u.item(0))
        Y_new = np.append(Y_new, u.item(1))
        Z_new = np.append(Z_new, u.item(2))

        ###Doing a dot product between F and c like you did earlier but using np.dot as we're now working with Numpy format
        side[i,:] = np.dot(F, c)

    ###Storing the position of every points
    sides = [[side[0],side[1],side[2],side[3]],
            [side[4],side[5],side[6],side[7]], 
            [side[0],side[1],side[4],side[5]], 
            [side[2],side[3],side[4],side[5]], 
            [side[1],side[2],side[5],side[6]],
            [side[4],side[7],side[0],side[3]]]


    ###Scatter plot 
    ax.scatter(X_new,Y_new,Z_new,c='darkred',marker='o')  #the  plot of points after rotated
    ax.scatter(ox,oy,oz,c='crimson',marker='o')  #the previous plot of points before rotated



    ### Add title 
    plt.title('Plot_for_PSM', fontsize=20)
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

    ##labelling the axes
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z')

    ###This draw the plane sides as you wanted
    ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(sides, facecolors='blue', linewidths=1, edgecolors='r', alpha=.25))


cuboid(center, size)
###Mandatory to plot the cube
plt.show()
```

It uses `Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection` from `mpl_toolkits` to draw 6 plane square, representing the sides of the cube.

The first step is to find the 4 coords of every side. Then you need to use `Poly3DCollection` to plot it.

Comment: I am attaining an error at this point. side[i,:] = np.dot(F, c)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3)

Comment: Did you change anything ? I don't have this error. 
Try using ``F.ravel()`` or ``c.ravel()`` in order to have a contiguous flattened array.

Comment: I have tried like this ......side[i,:] = np.dot(F.ravel(), c.ravel())

ValueError: shapes (1,9) and (1,3) not aligned: 9 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

Comment: No, i haven't changed anything. Just added the lines side from your code. Can you add a comment to each additional code that you added and the purpose it is doing?. So, that it gives a clear idea about the code how it is working......

Comment: Copy paste the whole code it will work better. But ok I'm editing it to explain.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can't i use this?? side[i,:] = np.dot(F, c).reshape(3)

Comment: Yes why not. You just need to find a way to do this dot product. 
I edited my answer to show you what I added with comments. 
Don't hesitate to mark this answer as accepted if it helps you.

Comment: Even i have copy paste the code i am attaining same error but this side[i,:] = np.dot(F, c).reshape(3)    code works perfect as the image you got. I need a clarity that whether to use this tatement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194875/discussion-between-pradeep-chakravarthi-nutakki-and-a-ben).

Comment: Hi i am obtaining this error during sometimes. `'Poly3DCollection' object has no attribute '_edgecolors2d'`